# Jquery Scripts on external page slides slow to load OR stalling out. What do I do?

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, jquery-plugins, jquery-lazyload

I am not sure what parts of the code to quote that would be relevant to solving my problem.  I have a test page here: http://www.guru3.com/filechute/pentco_new/

I am using several Jquery third party scripts / plugins, which are behaving erratically.

The scripts / plugins I am using are: 
 - Revolver sliding page plugin (http://2.s3.envato.com/files/27577254/index.html#/homepage)
 - Jpages pagination script (http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/)
 - Lazyload script (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

So the problem arises when I load two external page slides using the Jpages and Lazyload scripts consecutively.  When I load the first page, the scripts take a few seconds to actually load up and show the content and properly format it.  When I load the second page, the scripts just basically stop and do not load the menu or image content.  After refreshing the second page and a 2-3 second pause, the page would load up with the content.

So for the instance of the test page, the "Fullwrap > Material Options" and "Lamineer > Material Options" slides would be the pages in question.

Is there a way to get these pages to load up properly without having to refresh the browser?  And secondly, is there a way to mitigate the lag time experienced when the pages are rendering?

I am a rank amateur, so if there is something in my code that is "boneheaded-ish" I'd appreciate any illumination you can give me so I can learn to be not so "boneheaded."

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I'm stupid.  I was using the same ID name for the content containers for both of the pages.

Changed and it worked no problem.  I am a bonehead.

Comment: Also had to change the navigation container class in the css.